# Right way to say this

Tags: phrases

I was watching  a TV drama   along with my friend  recently when   this scene  came  up.
Scene  goes  something  like this :
Two  guys  were  having a conversation  when  a third  person  overhears their  conversation  from  a far distance .

I wanted to ask  my friend  "is it possible to  overhear  the conversation  to such a long distance". But I felt  that   something  was off with  the sentence . Is it  right to say  to such a long distance.  If  not  what  alternatives would you suggest

Comment: Could you [edit] your post to explain why you are concerned? Is there something specific you think is wrong? Otherwise, you might receive close votes as "proofreading".

Comment: "To a distance" is not really used in this sense anymore. You should say "from a distance".

Comment: In that sentence, I  would use "at".

Comment: “at” or “from” both work, but “to” does not.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is:

> Is it possible to overhear the conversation from such a distance?